# manipulação de alguma uma struct

Tags: c, c++

Eu tenho uma struct,
como faço pra predefinir dados nessa struct? exemplo definir vida da struct 100?

Já tentei `dataplyer.vida = 100;`

```
struct dataplayer
{
    int vida;
    int armadura;
    int arma;
    int level;
};
```

Comment: Qual o problema que está a ter ? A modificação não tem efeito ? Dá erro ? Se sim qual ? Não é muito claro para nós o que está a acontecer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema deve estar em outra área do código, aparentemente, você parece estar definindo corretamente o atributo. Então, suponho que seu problema seja outro, mas, respondendo a questão, basta usar o "." (ponto) para acessar o elemento de que você precisa e o operador de atribuição "=" para atribuir o valor.

Logicamente, você precisa criar uma "variável" para realizar a atribuição do valor real de um player na memória, no meu caso p1.

Segue um exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct dataplayer { int vida; int armadura; int arma; int level; };

int main()
{
    cout<<"definindo a vida \n";

    //seu player
    dataplayer p1;

    p1.vida = 100;

    cout << p1.vida;

    return 0;
}
```

Você pode testar esse codigo aqui:

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Obs.: Também não ficou claro para mim, e eu estou com sono, se você codifica em c ou c++, recomendo que escolha um.

Comment: Resolvido amigo! Vlw

Comment: ok marca a resposta na pergunta, t+

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi direito você quer que o campo vida tenha um valor padrão de 100 quando a struct for instanciada.
Se você estiver codificando em C infelizmente não é possível, pois não se pode atribuir valores a estruturas não instanciadas. Porém se estiver codificando em C++, onde structs trabalham exatamente da mesma forma que classes (porém com escopos padrão diferenciados) é possível resolver este problema com um construtor dentro da struct:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct dataplayer
{
    int vida;
    int armadura;
    int arma;
    int level;

    dataplayer() {
       this->vida = 100;
    }
};

int main() {

    struct dataplayer player; /*No momento da instancia o construtor sera chamado e
                                a vida sera alterada para 100 */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isso mesmo! Era isso que queria saber.  +1